# Column names not showing in random number generation using function 'rmsn' in R package 'sn'

Tags: r, random, rename, distribution, multivariate-testing

Using a dataframe, `df`, containing several S&P500 stocks monthly returns, I generated the inputs required for the multivariate random normal distribution function `rmsn` in the R package `sn`:

```
library(moments)
library(sn)
muvec = apply(df, 2, mean)
covmat = cov(df)
skew = apply(df, 2, skewness)
rmsn(100, muvec, covmat, skew)
```

However, the randomly generated numbers do not contain the original column headers in my input vectors (e.g. "A", "B", "C"). Instead, the output of `rmsn` contains generic names ("V1", "V2", "V3"). Is there a way to ensure that my original column headers are passed through into the output?

[image: Output of random number generation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `rmsn` is a matrix with no names and I am assuming you are using `as.data.frame` to convert it to a dataframe which gives it the default/geenric column names.

I think the only way is to assign the column names from `df`

```
out <- as.data.frame(sn::rmsn(100, muvec, covmat, skew))
names(out) <- names(df)
```